# Getting vertical gridlines to appear in line plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I want to get both horizontal and vertical grid lines on my plot but only the horizontal grid lines are appearing by default. I am using a `pandas.DataFrame` from an sql query in python to generate a line plot with dates on the x-axis. I'm not sure why they do not appear on the dates and I have tried to search for an answer to this but couldn't find one.

All I have used to plot the graph is the simple code below.

```
data.plot()
grid('on')
```

data is the DataFrame which contains the dates and the data from the sql query.

I have also tried adding the code below but I still get the same output with no vertical grid lines.

```
ax = plt.axes()        
ax.yaxis.grid() # horizontal lines
ax.xaxis.grid() # vertical lines
```

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: `data.plot(grid="on")` worked for me

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You may need to give boolean arg in your calls, e.g. use `ax.yaxis.grid(True)` instead of `ax.yaxis.grid()`.  Additionally, since you are using both of them you can combine into `ax.grid`, which works on both, rather than doing it once for each dimension.

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.grid(True)
```

That should sort you out.

Comment: I tried it but for some reason it still looks the same as before

Comment: Are you doing this in interactive interpreter?  Make sure you're setting the grid _before_ calling `plt.show()`

Comment: I am using iPython. I have tried adding plt.show() it won't make a difference.

Comment: Well this is odd.  What's your ipython version, also try running it like `ipython --pylab`, and do `plt.grid(True)` immediately - do you see the grid?

Comment: I tried `plt.grid(True)` and got the empty graph with both the vertical and horizontal grid lines, so yes it is odd why I can't get this for my line plot. I am running the latest available version of iPython.

Comment: Maybe there's one grid in 00:00 and no grid in others. I meet the same problem that only one grid in Nov 1 while no grid in other days.

Comment: Just plt.grid(True) will work.

Answer (score 70):

`plt.gca().xaxis.grid(True)` proved to be the solution for me

Comment: The `myaxes.grid(which='x')` wasn't working for me with matplotlib version 1.4.2... couldn't get the `which` keyword to work at all.  However, `myaxes.xaxis.grid(True)` did the trick and is conceptually better IMO.  Oh, and don't forget about the useful `myaxes.set_axisbelow(True)` method to put the grid behind the data.

Answer (score 36):

[According to matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.grid.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.grid), The signature of the `Axes` class `grid()` method is as follows:

> Axes.grid(b=None, which='major', axis='both', **kwargs)
>   Turn the axes grids on or off.
>
> `which` can be ‘major’ (default), ‘minor’, or ‘both’ to control whether
>   major tick grids, minor tick grids, or both are affected.
>
> `axis` can be ‘both’ (default), ‘x’, or ‘y’ to control which set of
>   gridlines are drawn.

So in order to show grid lines for both the x axis and y axis, we can use the the following code:

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.grid(which='major', axis='both', linestyle='--')
```

This method gives us finer control over what to show for grid lines.

Answer (score 16):

Short answer (read below for more info):

```
ax.grid(axis='both', which='both')
```

[image]

What you do is correct and it should work.

However, since the **X** axis in your example is a **DateTime** axis the **Major** tick-marks (most probably) are appearing only at the both ends of the X axis. The other visible tick-marks are **Minor** tick-marks.

The `ax.grid()` method, by default, draws grid lines on Major tick-marks.
Therefore, nothing appears in your plot.

Use the code below to highlight the tick-marks. Majors will be Blue while Minors are Red.

```
ax.tick_params(which='both', width=3)
ax.tick_params(which='major', length=20, color='b')
ax.tick_params(which='minor', length=10, color='r')
```

Now to force the grid lines to be appear also on the Minor tick-marks, pass the `which='minor'` to the method:

```
ax.grid(b=True, which='minor', axis='x', color='#000000', linestyle='--')
```

or simply use `which='both'` to draw both Major and Minor grid lines.
And this a more elegant grid line:

```
ax.grid(b=True, which='minor', axis='both', color='#888888', linestyle='--')
ax.grid(b=True, which='major', axis='both', color='#000000', linestyle='-')
```

Answer (score 8):

maybe this can solve the problem:
[matplotlib, define size of a grid on a plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10453770/matplotlib-define-size-of-a-grid-on-a-plot)

```
ax.grid(True, which='both')
```

The truth is that the grid is working, but there's only one v-grid in 00:00 and no grid in others. I meet the same problem that there's only one grid in Nov 1 among many days.

Answer (score 4):

For only horizontal lines

```
ax = plt.axes()        
ax.yaxis.grid() # horizontal lines
```

This worked

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
plt.grid(True)
```

This turns on both horizontal and vertical grids for date series with major tick marks in the right place.

Using Python3 / MatPlotLib 3.4.3