# Matplotlib pyplot - Plot graph with framelines

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

This should be quite easy, but I don't even know the right name of what I want.

I want to plot frame lines in my matplotlib graphs, basically, transform the left graph in the right graph in the picture below:

[image]

My code is basically:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1,squeeze=True,figsize=(16,14))

ax.plot(data1,negativeX,'g',linewidth=7)
ax.plot(data2,positiveX,'k')

for ax in fig.axes:
    ax.set_title(header)

plt.show()
```

Comment: maybe this, i don't have data so i can't plot it, plt.gca().xaxis.grid(True) # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16074392/getting-vertical-gridlines-to-appear-in-line-plot-in-matplotlib

Comment: Thank you :D - That's it