# Plotly: How to set values for major ticks / gridlines for timeseries on x-axis?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

**Background:**

This question is related, but not identical, to [Plotly: How to retrieve values for major ticks and gridlines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55118898/plotly-how-to-retrieve-values-for-major-ticks-and-gridlines). A similar question has also been asked but not answered for [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) here: [How do I show major ticks as the first day of each months and minor ticks as each day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30885715/how-do-i-show-major-ticks-as-the-first-day-of-each-months-and-minor-ticks-as-eac)

---

**Plotly is fantastic**, and maybe the only thing that bothers me is the autoselection of ticks / gridlines and the labels chosen for the x-axis like in this plot:

**Plot 1:**

[image]

I think the natural thing to display here is the ***first of each month*** (depending ong the period of course). Or maybe even just an abreviateed month name like `'Jan'` on each tick. I realize both the technical and even visual challenges due to the fact that all months are not of equal length. But does anyone know how to do this?

**Reproducible snippet:**

```
import plotly
import cufflinks as cf
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import HTML
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
import copy

# setup
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
np.random.seed(123)
cf.set_config_file(theme='pearl')

# Random data using cufflinks
df = cf.datagen.lines()
#df = df['UUN.XY']

fig = df.iplot(asFigure=True, kind='scatter',
               xTitle='Dates',yTitle='Returns',title='Returns')

iplot(fig)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*(updated answer for newer versions of plotly)*

With newer versions of plotly, you can specify `dtick = 'M1'` to set gridlines at the beginning of each month. You can also format the display of the month through `tickformat`:

#### Snippet 1

```
fig.update_xaxes(dtick="M2",
                 tickformat="%b\n%Y"
)
```

#### Plot 1

[image]

And if you'd like to set the gridlines at every second month, just change `"M1"` to `"M2"`

#### Plot 2

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
# imports
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

# data
df = px.data.stocks()
df = df.tail(40)
colors = px.colors.qualitative.T10

# plotly
fig = px.line(df,x = 'date',
                 y = [c for c in df.columns if c != 'date'],
                 template = 'plotly_dark',
                 color_discrete_sequence = colors,
                 title = 'Stocks', 
             )

fig.update_xaxes(dtick="M2",
                 tickformat="%b\n%Y"
)

fig.show()
```

---

**Old Solution:**

How to set the gridlines will depend entirely on what you'd like to display, and how the figure is built *before* you try to edit the settings. But to obtain the result specified in the question, you can do it like this.

**Step1:**

Edit `fig['data'][series]['x']` for each series in `fig['data']`.

**Step2:**

set tickmode and ticktext in:

```
go.Layout(xaxis = go.layout.XAxis(tickvals = [some_values]
                                  ticktext = [other_values])
          )
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Complete code for a Jupyter Notebook:**

```
# imports
import plotly
import cufflinks as cf
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import HTML
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
import copy
import plotly.graph_objs as go

# setup
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
np.random.seed(123)
cf.set_config_file(theme='pearl')
#%qtconsole --style vim

# Random data using cufflinks
df = cf.datagen.lines()

# create figure setup
fig = df.iplot(asFigure=True, kind='scatter',
               xTitle='Dates',yTitle='Returns',title='Returns')

# create df1 to mess around with while
# keeping the source intact in df
df1 = df.copy(deep = True)
df1['idx'] = range(0, len(df))

# time variable operations and formatting
df1['yr'] = df1.index.year
df1['mth'] = df1.index.month_name()

# function to replace month name with
# abbreviated month name AND year
# if the month is january
def mthFormat(month):
    dDict = {'January':'jan','February':'feb', 'March':'mar',
             'April':'apr', 'May':'may','June':'jun', 'July':'jul',
             'August':'aug','September':'sep', 'October':'oct',
             'November':'nov', 'December':'dec'}
    mth = dDict[month]
    return(mth)

# replace month name with abbreviated month name
df1['mth'] = [mthFormat(m) for m in df1['mth']]


# remove adjacent duplicates for year and month
df1['yr'][df1['yr'].shift() == df1['yr']] = ''
df1['mth'][df1['mth'].shift() == df1['mth']] = ''

# select and format values to be displayed
df1['idx'][df1['mth']!='']
df1['display'] = df1['idx'][df1['mth']!='']
display = df1['display'].dropna()
displayVal = display.values.astype('int')
df_display = df1.iloc[displayVal]
df_display['display'] = df_display['display'].astype('int')
df_display['yrmth'] = df_display['mth'] + '<br>' + df_display['yr'].astype(str)

# set properties for each trace
for ser in range(0,len(fig['data'])):

    fig['data'][ser]['x'] = df1['idx'].values.tolist()
    fig['data'][ser]['text'] = df1['mth'].values.tolist()
    fig['data'][ser]['hoverinfo']='all'

# layout for entire figure
f2Data = fig['data']
f2Layout = go.Layout(
    xaxis = go.layout.XAxis(
        tickmode = 'array',
        tickvals = df_display['display'].values.tolist(),
        ticktext = df_display['yrmth'].values.tolist(),
        zeroline = False)#,
)

# plot figure with specified major ticks and gridlines
fig2 = go.Figure(data=f2Data, layout=f2Layout)
iplot(fig2)
```

---

**Some important details:**

---

**1. Flexibility and limitations with `iplot()`:**

This approach with `iplot()` and editing all those settings is a bit clunky, but it's very flexible with regards to the number of columns / variables in the dataset, and arguably preferable to building each trace manually like `trace1 = go.Scatter()` for each and every column in the df.

**2. Why do you have to edit each series / trace?**

If you try to skip the middle part with

```
for ser in range(0,len(fig['data'])):

    fig['data'][ser]['x'] = df1['idx'].values.tolist()
    fig['data'][ser]['text'] = df1['mth'].values.tolist()
    fig['data'][ser]['hoverinfo']='all'
```

and try to set `tickvals` and `ticktext` directly on the entire plot, it will have no effect:

[image]

I think that's a bit weird, but I think it's caused by some underlying settings initiated by `iplot()`.

**3. One thing is still missing:**

In order fot thie setup to work, the structure of `ticvals` and `ticktext` is `[0, 31, 59, 90]` and `['jan<br>2015', 'feb<br>', 'mar<br>', 'apr<br>']`, respectively. This causes the xaxis line hovertext show the position of the data where `ticvals` and `ticktext` are empty:

[image]

Any suggestions on how to improve the whole thing is highly appreciated. Better solutions than my own will instantly receive ***Accepted Answer*** status!