# Impose minor grid on plot with y log scale, using Python

Tags: python, grid, logarithm

I'm making some plots with mathplotlib, the y axis is in log scale. I want to have both major and minor grids on both X and Y axis. The first plot comes out perfect (meaning that my code works), while in the second plot the y-minorgrid is suppressed (I assume for ease of visualisation reasons). I want to overcome this and impose the presence of y-minorgrid, even if the resulting plot looks less clear.
Any suggestion?
Current code is

```
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=[18, 10])
    axes.plot(DF['value'])
    axes.set_title('whatever')
    axes.set_ylabel('Pressure [mbar]')
    axes.set_xlabel('time [s]')
    axes.set_yscale('log')
    axes.set_ylim([1E-8, 10000])
    axes.grid(b=True, which='minor', color='orange', linestyle=':')
    axes.grid(b=True, which='major')
    axes.minorticks_on()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at this post below that may be helpful to your scenario. Good luck!

[matplotlib: Setting both major and minor ticks forces same x and y scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24963711/matplotlib-setting-both-major-and-minor-ticks-forces-same-x-and-y-scale)

Comment: Hi, it was sort of helpful to understand how to set the ticks manually, despite not being the answer to my question. My problem is solved now, using this solution:```axes.set_yscale('log')
    axes.legend(loc='best')

    axes.set_yticks(minor_ticks, minor=True)
    axes.set_yticks(major_ticks, minor=False)
    axes.grid(b=True, which='minor', color='orange', linestyle=':')
    axes.grid(b=True, which='major')```