# How can I get the y-axis in degrees from 180 to 180° using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis

I'm using matplotlib and I want my y axis to count like this

```
180°, 270°, 360°, 90°, 180°
```

Is there a way to do this? When I use set_ylim I can only manage it from 0-360°!

Comment: The problem is not clear enough. Please provide a [mcve] by [edit]ing your question, showing how you produce the ticks from 0-360°. Extending this to the range 180-180 should be straight forward, so it would be good to explain where exactly the problem lies.

Comment: This question is unclear but I think what you are referring to is called y ticks in matplotlib.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/24943991/2597135 for example.