# labels lost while adjusting ticks in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I draw some line plot for a monthly time series, which starts 
in 1999 with this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
url = ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mini-kep/parser-rosstat-kep/'
       'master/data/processed/latest/dfm.csv')
dfm =  pd.read_csv(url, converters={0: pd.to_datetime}, index_col=0)
ax = dfm.iloc[:,3:5].plot()
```

[image]

At this point I have major and minor ticks and x ticks lables. The desired change is alter the position of major ticks so that they start in 2000 and end 2020, every 5 years.  I'm able to to that with code below ([following this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24943991/change-grid-interval-and-specify-tick-labels-in-matplotlib)), but the price I pay is that the tick labels disappear. I was not able to bring them back with `plt.xticks`. Another minor error that my ticks are now at year-end, not year start as wanted.

```
major_ticks = pd.date_range('2000', '2020', freq='5Y')
ax.set_xticks(major_ticks)
# below dows not help to add back major tick labels 
# plt.xticks(label=[t.year for t in major_ticks])
minor_ticks = pd.date_range('1998', '2020', freq='Y')
ax.set_xticks(minor_ticks, minor=True)
```

[image]

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Update:

The code in my question followed [this suggestion for changing the position of major ticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24943991/change-grid-interval-and-specify-tick-labels-in-matplotlib).

However, it got marked as [duplicate of the question, that explains tick label formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44213781/pandas-dataframe-line-plot-display-date-on-xaxis). It had useful clues, so the ultimate code that works is below:

```
# x_compat=True - an important part
ax = dfm.iloc[:,3:5].plot(x_compat=True)        
# set minor ticks
minor_ticks = pd.date_range('1998', '2020', freq='YS')
ax.set_xticks(minor_ticks, minor=True)
# set major ticks
major_ticks = pd.date_range('2000', '2020', freq='5YS') 
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(major_ticks, minor=False)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%Y'))
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate(rotation=0, ha="center")
```

[image]

Comment: "I'm able to to that with code ..." - I would rather say you are not able to do it, because you kill the ticks and labels using `xticks`. There are many questions on how to change the datetime ticks with matplotlib, did you look at any of them?

Comment: As for questions: I attached a link to the question I reproduced in my code. I managed to move the tick positions with it, but confused what call should reassign the labels.

Comment: there is no explicit call to xticks, it is commented out, unless .set_xticks calls it