# Represent a continuous graph using `matplotlib` and `pandas`

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, data-science

My dataframe is like this-

```
   Energy_MWh    Month
0   39686.82    1979-01
1   35388.78    1979-02
2   50134.02    1979-03
3   37499.22    1979-04
4   20104.08    1979-05
5   17440.26    1979-06
```

It goes on like this to the month 2015-12. So you can imagine all the data.

I want to plot a continuous graph with the `months` as the *x-axis* and the `Energy_MWh` as the *y-axis*. How to best represent this using `matplotlib`?

I would also like to know for my knowledge if there's a way to print `1979-01` as `Jan-1979` on the *x-axis* and so on. Probably a lambda function or something while plotting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Borrowed liberally from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43631028/1717828), which you should go out and upvote:

```
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter

df = <set_your_data_frame_here>

myDates = pd.to_datetime(df['Month'])
myValues = df['Energy_MWh']
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(myDates,myValues)

myFmt = DateFormatter("%b-%Y")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)

## Rotate date labels automatically
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I wanted. My current x-axis labels are `Jan 1979, Jan 1983, Jan 1987...`. Is there a way I could show more intervals? For example, instead of an interval of 4 years, I want it to be 2 years.

Comment: I know next to nothing about matplotlib, but I [searched your question](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22matplotlib%22+%22interval+of+4+years%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) and found [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24943991/1717828) that seems very similar.  The accepted (and only) answer there is code I would copy/paste here, but I'm sure you'll be able to adapt it to your own use case yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Set `Month` as the index:

```
df.set_index('Month', inplace=True)
```

Convert the index to `Datetime`:

```
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index)
```

Plot:

```
df.plot()
```