# How to do xticklabel with different major grid spacing

Tags: python, matplotlib, xticks, gridlines

How to plot a chart with minor grid of 1, major grid of 10, and with xticklabels increment **20 units**?

Here is my sample code and output with xticklabels increment every 10 units:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = plt.gca()
major_ticks = np.arange(0, 60, 10)    
minor_ticks = np.arange(0, 60, 1)
ax.set_xticks(major_ticks)
ax.set_xticks(minor_ticks, minor=True)
ax.set_yticks(major_ticks)
ax.set_yticks(minor_ticks, minor=True)
ax.grid(which='major')
ax.grid(which='minor', alpha=0.5)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
```

[image]

But then I wanted to display the xticklabels and yticklabels with the increment of 20 instead of 10, as shown here like this:

[image]

Any idea how to accomplish this? Thanks

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24943991/change-grid-interval-and-specify-tick-labels-in-matplotlib/24953575) you will see how to use major and minor ticks

Comment: Hi @Bazingaa, thanks for your reply, but the link that you provide did not solve this particular problem.

Comment: It was not a direct answer but I gave you the links which could guide you in the right direction. Anyway, I answered now. Have a look at it below.

Comment: Thanks @Bazingaa! Great solution. Btw, do you know how to turn of all tick marks except those the location that has the xticklabels turn on?

Comment: Check my edited answer

Comment: hi Bazingaa, all answers given so far are good answers that solve my problem.After reading your message, I now realize that I cannot accept 2 answers. Really, sorry about that. I am going to pick the best answer then. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add the following 4 lines to the end of your code: You just have to hide every second major tick label. That's pretty much it to get what you want. `[1::2]` indexing means start from the second index and take every second element from there. I have to start from the second index because the tick label at the first index is 0 which you do not want to remove.

EDIT: IF you just want the major ticks at the locations where you have tick labels, you can do the following modifications (marked by an arrow `<---`). Yo might find the [official docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/axis_api.html#matplotlib.axis.Tick) helpful.

**Plot without the major ticks but with minor ticks**

```
# Hiding for x-axis
for t in ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks()[1::2]:
    t.label.set_visible(False)
    t.tick1On = False # <----

# Hiding for y-axis
for t in ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks()[1::2]:
    t.label.set_visible(False)    
    t.tick1On = False # <----
```

[image]

**Plot without the minor and major ticks**

If you also want to hide the minor ticks, you can do the following in addition to the above code

```
for t in ax.xaxis.get_minor_ticks():
    t.tick1On = False
    # t._apply_params(width=0) # suggested by Jayjayyy

for t in ax.yaxis.get_minor_ticks():
    t.tick1On = False     
    # t._apply_params(width=0) # suggested by Jayjayyy
```

The direct way avoiding all for loops is as suggested by [Jayjayyy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1621041/jayjayyy)

```
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', width=0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the appreciation. I had to look it up in my laptop for my work related notebooks where I used similar things a long time ago ;) But sometimes I just discover new options by using a tab completion after typing `ax.`

Comment: @Jayjayyy: I added your suggestion. Thanks

Comment: I haven’t used it so far. I just added jayjay suggestion

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

That looks maybe a little bit nicer:

```
ax.set_xticklabels(['' if i % 2 else l for i, l in enumerate(ax.get_xticks())])
ax.set_yticklabels(['' if i % 2 else l for i, l in enumerate(ax.get_yticks())])
```

---

I think you'll have to manually set every second label to `''`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = plt.gca()
major_ticks = np.arange(0, 60, 10)    
minor_ticks = np.arange(0, 60, 1)
ax.set_xticks(major_ticks)
ax.set_xticks(minor_ticks, minor=True)
ax.set_yticks(major_ticks)
ax.set_yticks(minor_ticks, minor=True)
ax.grid(which='major')
ax.grid(which='minor', alpha=0.5)
ax.set_aspect('equal')

xticks = ax.get_xticks().tolist()
for i in range(1, len(xticks), 2):
    xticks[i] = ''
ax.set_xticklabels(xticks)

yticks = ax.get_yticks().tolist()
for i in range(1, len(yticks), 2):
    yticks[i] = ''
ax.set_yticklabels(yticks)

plt.show()
```

And plots:

[image: plot]

Comment: hi Jayjayyy, that's exactly what I need. Thank you very much!!

Comment: hi Jayjayyy, how to turn off all tick marks except those that has xticklabel?