# How set a specific range of x-axis and increase the length of the plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I´m looking to add a specific range of values to the x-axis of my plot and increase the length of this axis.
I change the range of the values of my x-axis; however, the values keep in a specific range.
Besides, I tried to increase the length of the x-axis but I failed again.
For now, I´m only plotting an empty graph, because a need to set the specifications for the axis.
Here is part of the code to the plot:

```
fig1, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_xlim(1, 1200)
ax.set_ylim(-800, 200)
ax.set_box_aspect(1)

plt.show()
```

This code gives me a plot square with the range of the:

```
x-axis = 0-200-400...1200,
```

I´m looking for:

```
x-axis = 0-50-100-150...1200
```

Also, I need to change the shape of the plot: square to a rectangular, where the x-axis increases the length.
Any suggestion or comment is welcome!

Thank!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`plt.figure(figsize=(15,2))`

Use this at first line to set the size of your plot. As you want to increase x-axis, then see that x>y in figsize parameter.

```
l1=np.arange(0,1250,50)
plt.xticks(l1)
```

Use the above code after setting y limits to set the xticks in range of 0-1200 with gap of 50.
``

Answer (score 0):

You can change the size (and therefore the shape) of a pyplot figure like this:

```
fig1.set_size_inches(10, 8)
```

As for the ticks on the axis, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24943991/change-grid-interval-and-specify-tick-labels-in-matplotlib) gives a pretty in-depth answer on how to customize those.