# How do I change the grid size?

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is what I want:

[image: properly spaced grid]

This is what I currently have:

[image: my grid]

This is my code so far:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

l = [-1, 1, -10, 10]
plt.axis(l)
plt.grid()
```

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks/major_minor_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-ticks-major-minor-demo-py

Comment: ignore all references to minor ticks in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76801093/19123103) and just use major tick locators and you got your desired grid (with `MultipleLocator(0.25)` for xaxis and `MultipleLocator(2.5)` for yaxis)